# how to add color to blocks inline in css?

Tags: html, css

I start learning css and have a trouble with adding color to blocks, which stay in the same line. As you can see, in [My website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u8JuR.png) on the first line the color is out of the border of each block. What I want to do is make it looks like in the [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JARgN.jpg) (the 3 green blocks). Can anybody help me fix it?

ps: sorry, my English is not so good :/

both are my css and html codes:

```css
   

body
{
    font-family: inherit;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}



#menu1 {
    float: left;
    padding-left: 50px;
}

#menu2 {
    float: right;
    padding-right: 50px;
}


.nav {
    position: relative;
    top: -5px;
    padding: 9px 0px 50px 0px;
    background-color: aliceblue;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.nav ul, li {
    display: inline-block
    border: 1px black solid;
    background-color: orange;
}
.nav ul,li,a {
    display: inline-block;

}

.titel {
    background-color: antiquewhite;
    position: relative;
    top: -9px;
    padding: 75px 0px 75px 0px;
}

.titel h1,h4 {
    text-align: center;
    color: skyblue;
    text-shadow: 2px 1px grey;
}

.hometext {
    margin: 0px 25px 0px 25px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>     
        <title>My Website</title>
        <link rel ="stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "style.css"/>
    </head>

    <body> 
    
<!--    <h1 class="blue">Titel 1</h1>
        <h1 id= "heading">Heading</h1>
        
        <p class = "blue">Welcome to my website, my name is Unknow and it's a pleasure for me to see you guys!!!!</p>-->
        
        <div class="nav">
        
            <ul id="menu1">
                <li><a href = "#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href = "#">About</a></li>
                <li><a href = "#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>

            <ul id="menu2">
                <li><a href = "#">Sign up</a></li>
                <li><a href = "#">Log in</a></li>
                <li><a href = "#">Help</a></li>
            </ul>
        
        </div>
        
        <div class="titel">
        
            <h1>---MY WEBSITE---</h1>
            <h4>Welcome to my first website</h4>
        </div>
        
        <div class="hometext">
                
                <h2>Homepage</h2>

        </div>
    
    </body>



</html>
```

Comment: Hey Owl, you need to post the code from your website, not just a screenshot.

Comment: Break the code down to the problematic part, and post that portion of the code here

Comment: sorry, I forgot posting my codes :)

Answer (score 0):

Before you start with the CSS, you are going to have to think about the markup. Your list of 'boxes' looks like a 'list' of something... in this case navigation links. This is how I would suggest writing the markup.

```
<nav class='site-navigation'>
  <ul class='item-list'>
    <li class='item'>
      <a href='#'>Item name</a>
    </li>
    <li class='item'>
      <a href='#'>Item name</a>
    </li>
    <li class='item'>
      <a href='#'>Item name</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

from there... you'll style it.

```
ul {
  /* reset the annoying defaults of lists */
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit; /* inherit from parent color */
}

.site-navigation .item-list .item {
  display: inline-block;
}

.site-navigation .item-list a {
  display: block; /* make sure these links (inline by default) are block */
  padding: 10px 20px;
  background: lightgreen;
  color: white;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/cm5kbxx3/

The question 'how do I color these boxes' should tell you that it's time for some studying. It's only going to get about 100x more difficult. Find a good class or mentor. frontendmasters or codementor are good ways to level up quickly. Be sure and post some code next time - along with what you've tried so far. : )

Comment: thanks for your advice. I've tried your codes but it doesnt fix it.

Comment: Instead of trying to 'fix' it... you need to actually learn CSS if you are going to be doing this often.